# SQL database. I dropped a table, how can I now create it?

Tags: django, sqlite

To drop table I used that command:

```
python manage.py dbshell
.tables
DROP TABLE table_what_i_drop;
```

Then I tried:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

but the table wasn't created.

I deleted migrations folders from all apps and the dbsqlite3 file and tried again `makemigrations` and `migrate`, but databases wasn't created. Now when I tried:

python manage.py dbshell
.tables

there are no tables for any of my apps. I know that losing tables is my fault, but how I can make all databases from the beginning?

Comment: if you are using `sqlite` then, delete the Sqlite file then do migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps in migrations - make migrations and  migrate.

**makemigrations** creates the migration file based on database changes.

**migrate** runs the migrations and makes the database changes. It also logs what migrations have been run in the table:

```
django_migrations
```

You deleted the migrations folder,but there will still be an entry in django migrations saying that your previous migrations have run.

So to fix this, go to the django_migrations table and remove the entries related to your app (there will also be entries for Django tables, such as auth and contenttypes, so don't delete those)

(Alternately just delete the whole sqllite database and start from scratch if you don't mind loosing data in the database)

Comment: That was real pain in the ***. I deleted all migrations folders from apps(i don't know why i  did that) and migrate and makemigrations commands stopped to work for my apps. That is good that i made a copy of  project before deleting something. So i replaced all my changes with saved files. In the end i deleted db.sqlite3 file , made some changes in models and makemigrations and  migrate started to work properly.